# JavaScript Not Working - CSS Elements incorrect?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Again I have tried putting this script in to a website and it is not functioning correctly...

Can someone please help me understand what may be malfunctioning?

UPDATE:

My tested code which works in another instance:

```
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('').fadeOut('slow');
            $('#logo-img img')
                .css({'width':'216px','height':'73px'})
                .attr('src','http://...logo_01_white.png');
        }
        if($(this).scrollTop() < 100) {
            $('').fadeIn('fast');
            $('#logo-img img')
                .css({'width':'216px','height':'73px'})    
                .attr('src','http://...logo_01.png');
        }
    });
});
```

The website I am trying to implement my code on:

http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/52089.html

Can anyone see where these lines may have been calling the wrong classes?

```
$('.logo.pull-left').fadeOut('slow');
     $('.logo_h.logo_h__img')
```

Comment: If `logo pull-left` are classes then you need to write it as `.logo .pull-left`. All the classes should have dots `.` before and for ids `#` before.

Comment: is `logo pull-left` is a class or a id selector .

Comment: if logo pull-left and logo_h logo_h__img are classes then write .logo  .put-left and .logo_h .logo_h_img.

Comment: Much appreciated though it still isn't working....

Here is the html too
<div class="logo pull-left">
         <a href="http://..." class="logo_h logo_h__img"><img src="http://dev.....logo_01.png" alt="Test" title=""></a>
    </div>

<a href="http://dev.../" class="logo_h logo_h__img"><img src="http://dev....logo_01.png" alt="Test" title=""></a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        $('logo pull-left').fadeOut('slow');
```

Here `logo` is not an tag element.

You must specify `.logo` if its CSS class or `#logo` if its CSS ID.

Similarly for `logo_h__img` , `pull-left` as well. You must specify whether it's class.

So your corrected code will be like below:

> Update based on your CODE

In your code, both `logo` and `pull-left` classes are in same dom element. SO you must use `.logo.pull-left`

```
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.logo.pull-left').fadeOut('slow');
            $('.logo_h.logo_h__img')
                .css({'width':'216px','height':'73px'})
                .attr('src','http://....1.png');
        }
        if($(this).scrollTop() < 100) {
            $('.logo.pull-left').fadeIn('fast');
            $('.logo_h.logo_h__img')
                .css({'width':'216px','height':'73px'})    
                .attr('src','http://...2.png');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: share your HTML here to help you better

Comment: Added the HTML and another PHP file which related to the scrolling navigation to the original question. Thanks.

Comment: Ok so I created a test css class and tested my code with that and it works. Though doesn't return to original logo upon a scroll up!

Still can't figure this out... Is it more complicated than I think ?

Comment: `logo` and `pull-left` are in same level. So you must change your selector. it must be `$('.logo.pull-left')` and similarly `$('.logo_h logo_h__img')`

Comment: I have attempted this & still couldn't get it to work though the test is working... 

I will provide a demo link of where I am testing my code and my updated code

Answer (score 0):

Updating image source will not display the new image, that's a problem that I also had on my website. So you should remove the previous image then place a new one

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var img1 = '<img src="http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2014/4/11/1397210130748/Spring-Lamb.-Image-shot-2-011.jpg">'
  var img2 = '<img src="http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/spaceimages/images/mediumsize/PIA17011_ip.jpg">'
  
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.pull-left').fadeOut('slow');
            $('.logo_h.logo_h__img').children('img').remove();
            $('.logo_h.logo_h__img').append(img1);
        }
        if($(this).scrollTop() < 100) {
            $('.pull-left').fadeIn('fast');
            $('.logo_h.logo_h__img').children('img').remove();
            $('.logo_h.logo_h__img').append(img2);
        }
    });
});
```

```css
body { height: 2000px; }
img { position: fixed; }
.logo_h__img img { width: 216px; height: 73px; right: 0; left: 0; margin: auto; }
.pull-left img { width: 200px; height: 200px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="logo_h logo_h__img"><img src="http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/spaceimages/images/mediumsize/PIA17011_ip.jpg"></div>
<div class="logo pull-left"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Dell_Logo.png/1027px-Dell_Logo.png"></div>
```